# Why can't I declare a property as System.IO.Path

Tags: vb.net, .net

I am using a custom class to pass data between methods.  One of the primary functions is image handling so I have an image path and a custom thumb path as properties of my class.  I want to use the methods included with the `System.IO.Path` class as part of the properties, but I can't seem to do it this way.

I know how to get this to work by using a `string` type instead of `System.IO.Path` as a type so I don't need anyone to tell me how to do it that way.  I just think that being able to declare my `ImagePath` as `System.IO.Path` would be so much easier because I can use the `Path` methods on my `ImagePath` property.  I must be missing some understanding about declaring types and I'm hoping I can learn from this question.

How the class is defined:

```
Public Class myClass
    'structured information which will be passed to a replicator

    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property ImagePath As System.IO.Path '<== this doesn't work
    Public Property ThumbPath As System.IO.Path '<== this doesn't work
    Public Property GroupID As Byte
    Public Property SystemID As Byte
    Public Property Comment As String
    'Other properties
End Class
```

How I would like to use this class:

```
Public Function myReplicatorFunc(myObj as myClass)
    Dim myTempPath as string
    Dim myDBObj as myDBConnection

    'handle database connections

    myTempPath = myObj.ImagePath.GetDirectoryName() & "\" _
        myDBObj.GetIntID.toString() & "\" _
        myObj.ImagePath.GetExtension()

    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(myObj.ThumbPath.toString, myTempPath)

    'Other file movements for replication etc
End Function
```

Why can't I declare a property as a System.IO.Path class?  If the answer is just "NO" for some reason (please explain why) then how can I use the `System.IO.Path` methods as extensions to my properties without re-writing as a custom class with exact copies of the same methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot declare an instance of [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) because it's a static class - it cannot be instantiated. Think of it as simply a grouping of path-related global functions under a `System.IO.Path` namespace. (The real namespace is just `System.IO` but because `Path` is a static class, functionally it really behaves as if was just a namespace for a bunch of related global functions.)

Your `ImagePath` property needs to be `string` and you just need to pass it to `Path` functions when you need that logic. This is somewhat unfortunate.

As an alternative, you can create a new class (sorry, C# code; I'm not a VB.NET expert):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
// import namespaces as necessary

public class Filename
{
    private string m_sFilename;

    public Filename ( string sFilename )
    {
        m_sFilename = sFilename;
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return ( m_sFilename );
        }
        set
        {
            m_sFilename = value;
        }
    }

    public string FolderName
    {
        get
        {
            return ( Path.GetDirectoryName ( m_sFilename ) );
        }
    }

    // Add more properties / methods
    ...
}
```

Once you have this class, you can write:

```
private Filename m_oImagePath = null;
```

I did pretty much the same in my project because having a specific type for folder / file paths makes it easier to update logic related to operations on path names.

Comment: I can build this class in VB.NET no problem.  After asking the question I was thinking this could be the easiest way to do it.  I was hoping it would be more automatic but alas, apparently I can't have my cake and eat it too.  Thank you for the explanations of the difference between an class and namespace.

Comment: @turbonate Yes, I agree with you - it'd be better if it was easier to do this; I find this workaround a little bit clunky. I'm glad this helped - thanks for the vote.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `DirectoryInfo` like:

```
Public Property ImagePath As System.IO.DirectoryInfo
Public Property ThumbPath As System.IO.DirectoryInfo
```

Comment: This almost works, I might inherit this class in combination with what xxbbcc is suggesting.  The only issue is that `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` doesn't have `GetExtension` and `GetFileName` since it is a directory class rather than a full file operating class.